# How to determine if a matrix has positive eigenvalues without resorting to the characteristic polynomial?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

I have a non-symmetric sparse matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ whose diagonal entries are either $0$ or negative. Is there a way to determine if this matrix has any positive eigenvalue or a complex eigenvalue with a positive real part?

Notice that I can't calculate its polynomial characteristics or determinant since it's a huge matrix.

Comment: Maybe Gershgorin Circle Theorem could help you (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

Comment: If your diagonal elements are strictly negative, the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) can sometimes tell you that the matrix *doesn't* have an eigenvalue with a positive real part, which you may find useful. However, it will inconclusive otherwise (it will not affirm or deny the existence of such eigenvalues), particularly in the case when the diagonal elements are nonpositive but not all strictly negative.

Comment: Would non-negative instead of positive work for you?

Comment: Does the matrix have any special structure? What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, This is the state matrix of my system and I need to be sure this state matrix makes my system unstable. So, non-negative doesn't work for me. It has to be either positive or a complex eigenvalue with a positive real part. .

Comment: About the special structure, the diagonal block matrixes look like $[0, 376; n/p/z, n]$ where `n` means negative, `p` means positive and `z` is zero. I hope it helps you

Comment: So, marginal stability is good enough for you. You don't need asymptotic stability. Note that eigenvalues on the imaginary axis are dangerous. There is a reason I mentioned non-negative.